# Tell if there exists boxes with equal content

Tags: algorithms

Assume that we have a device which takes $2$ boxes and tells if their content is equal or not.

Given $n$ boxes with identical appearance, but different content, You are asked to design an algorithm which tells if there exist $n/2$ boxes with equal contents.

Hint: Think of the divide and conquer approach.

Note: The algorithm should run in $O(nlogn)$ time.

My try: We divide these $n$ boxes into $2$ groups. If the boxes in $1$ group have the same content, we are done. If not, we should seek for $n/2$ boxes such that some of them are from the first group and some of them come from the second group. So, if comparing two boxes with the device takes $O(1)$ time, How can i say if there are $n/2$ boxes having equal content, some of them from the first group and some from the second group? (That's where i'm stuck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem becomes simpler if we make it harder:

Given $n$ boxes of respective contents $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, we will use our device to collect specimens of all subsets of size $\ge\frac n2$ of boxes of equal content. That is, the algorithm will return

- the empty set $\{\}$ if no subset of $\frac n2$ boxes of equal content exists
- a one element set $\{i\}$ such that there are $\ge \frac n2$ boxes of content $x_i$, but no other content occurs $\frac n2$ times.
- a two element set $\{i,j\}$ where the $i$th and $j$th box have different contents, $x_i\ne x_j$, but both contents occur at least (and hence exactly) $\frac n2$ times
- it is impossible that three or more should be returned

For a divide and conquer approach, note that if a content occurs in at least half of all boxes and we take any subset of all boxes, then said content will occur for at least half of the boxes of said subset or for at least half of the boxes of the complement of said subset. Expressed more formally: If $\frac ab\le \frac cd$ with $b,d>0$ are the proportions of boxes of said content in two disjoint subsets of sizes $b$  and $d$, then a $\frac ab\le \frac{a+c}{b+d}\le \frac cd$ holds for the proportion of such boxed in the union.

Thus we do as follows:

Given an $n$ element index set $I$ and a device that, given $i,j\in I$,  can tell if the $i$th box and the $j$th box have equal content or not ...

- If $n=0$, return $\{\}$. Clearly,  there cannot be any specimen. (Nevertheless, the answer to the OP question is "yes": there are zero boxes of pairwise same content!)
- If $n=1$ and our one-element index set is $I=\{i\}$ and our only box has weight $x_i$, then return $I$ itself. Clearly, one, which is more than half of on, box has weight $x_i$.
- If $n=2$, $I=\{i,j\}$, then if $x_i=x_j$ return $\{i\}$,  but if $x_i\ne x_j$ return  $\{i,j\}$.
- If $n>2$, paritition the boxes into two nearly equal-sized subsets. That is if $n=2m+r$ with $m\ge1$ and $r\in\{0,1\}$, write $I=I_1\cup I_2$ with $|I_1|=m$ and $|I_2|=m+r$; let $L_1$ be the result of the algorithm applied to $I_1$ and $L_2$ the result of the algorithm applied to $I_2$. For each of the up to four elements of $L_1\cup L_2$ (with duplicate contents removed by at most $4$ comparisons of elements of $L_1$ vs. $L_2$), check how often they occur in $I$. Return those indices with $\ge\frac n2$ occurances.

Apparently the number of invocations of the comparison device is bounded by
 $T(0)=T(1)=0$, $T(2)=1$, and $T(n)=T(\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor)+T(\lceil \frac n2\rceil)+4n$. As these dominate the execution time, we arrive at the desired $O(n\log n)$.

For convenience, here is some C-like pseudo code

```
bool atleasthalf(int test, int begin, int end) {
   // calls is_same_content at most end-begin-1 times
   int found = 0;
   for(int i= begin; i<end; i++)
      if (i==test || is_same_content(i,test))
         found++;
   return 2*found >= end-begin;
}

class twoorlessints {
private:
   int data[2];
   int count;
public:
int getcount() const { return count; }
int operator[](int x) const {
   assert(x>=0 && x<count);
   return data[x];
}
twoorlessint(): count(0) {}
void append(int x) { 
   assert(count<2);
   data[count++]=x;
}
twoorlessint(int x): count(0) {append(x);}
twoorlessint(int x, int y): count(0) {append(x);append(y);}
};

twoorlessints get_specimens(int begin, int end) {
   assert(end>begin);
   if (end==begin+1) return twoorlessints(begin);
   int middle = (begin+end)/2;
   twoorlessints L1 = get_specimens(begin, middle); // T(floor(n/2))
   twoorlessints L2 = get_specimens(middle, end); // T(ceil(n/2))
   for (int i=0; i<L1.getcount(); i++) 
      for (int j=L2.getcount()-1; j>=0; j--)
         if (is_same_content(L1[i],L2[j])) // at most four invokations
            L2.droplast();
   twoorlessints L;
   for (int i=0; i<L1.getcount(); i++) 
      if (atleastalf(L1[i],begin,end))
         L.append(L1[i]);
   for (int i=0; i<L2.count; i++) 
      if (atleastalf(L2[i],begin,end))
         L.append(L2[i]);
   return L;
}

bool main_question(int n) {
   if (n==0) 
      return true; // special case of vacuous truth
   else
      return get_specimens(1,n+1).count>0;
}
```

Comment: Would you please simplify your answer? I can't understand! You are given $n$ boxes and a device. What do u do?